# How to close Parent form without closing child form in Windows form in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to make one windows application which contains two forms. In form1(Parent) i  created one button for open second form. On that button click event i want to close form1(parent) form and open form2(child) without closing form2, but when i am press that button both forms are closed so how can I do it?

Comment: The lifetime of the app is tied to whatever form you pass to `Application.Run()` in `program.cs`. When that form closes, the Application closes as well, which is why the app exits when you close Form1.  If you want to have finer control over when the app closes pass your own instance of [ApplicationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext).

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Comment: Ok , I will do it.

Comment: @MeetPanchal Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: It's work properly.Thanks for your kind help

Comment: @MeetPanchal I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `.Close()` consider using `.Hide()` on your parent form, this shouldn't dispose of it but rather have it hidden.

Note that exiting out of your Child form means your application won't exit. To circumvent this you should consider subscribing to the `OnFormClosed` event to handle the form closure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close form1(parent) form and open form2(child) form without closing form2 by click the button, you can refer to the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        Hide();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        Close();
    }
```

If you want to open the parent form after the child form is closed, you can refer to this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        Hide();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        Show();
    }
```

**Here is the test result**
[image]

Comment: This method work successfully in my program and it helps me a lot. But one issue accure when i use this methos is that when i want to close this program than first i have to close child form and after parent form hide so i have to stop debugging directly. So i think this not good practice so look at to find this solution.If you have any suggestion so share with me.

Comment: @MeetPanchal I modified my code, parent form will be closed when child form is closed. If you want to redisplay the parent form after the child form is closed, you can use the second code. If my answer can solve your problem, you can click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in "Program.cs" there is a form to start with.
When this form is closed, the application is terminated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMs6o.png)

It should be used as a way to hide the startup form.

Even if the child form is closed with the start form hidden, the program does not end.

As @Ae774 said, you need to handle it separately.